# How do I make a button stay "Pressed" after clicking

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I need code please

i need a button when I click, the button will stay pressed.

I feel so embarrassed sometimes, because I seem to get tripped up by these most trivial things,  I really appreciate this community's help any answer that pushes me forward is always appreciated!

Thank!! :)

Comment: Please post any code you've tried.

Comment: "_I need code please_" Then you are in the wrong place. Please see the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my sulotion (need to use a Directive)

--html

button.component.html

```
<button  class="btn btn-danger" style="width: 110px" appButton"
         ></button>
```

--Typescript

button.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appButton]'
})
export class ButtonDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

@HostListener('mousedown') onmousedown(eventData: Event) {
   if (this.elRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor === 'blue') {
     this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'rgba(200,0,0,0.7)');
   } else {
     this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');

   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try to achieve this by styling you button.

For example:

```
<input type="button" style="border-style:inset;" />
```

This border type should make your button look like it is pressed constantly.

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<button id="myBtn" onclick="changeText()" [disabled]="disabled" >{{buttonText}}</button>
```

Comp

```
buttonText = "Press Here"
disabled = false

changeText() { 
    const button = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    if (button.classList.contains('pressed') { 
        return;
    } else {
        this.buttonText = "Pressed";
        button.classList.add('pressed');
        this.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.pressed {
    background: "something darker then your unclicked button background color"
}
```